# vim airline how to show full warning messages

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I am using vim + vim-airline, and it looks like this in my terminal:
[image]
as you can see, it just shows a bit of the warnings, is this intended?
It will show more if I lengthen the window, but how can I set it to show the full warning messages for the current window size? for example, if I can adjust the section width or do something else?

In my `.vimrc` I have

```
 28 set laststatus=2                                                                
 27 let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1                                               
 26 let g:airline_theme='luna'                                                      
 25 let g:airline#extensions#default#section_truncate_width = {                     
 24             \ 'b': 79,                                                          
 23             \ 'x': 60,                                                          
 22             \ 'y': 50,                                                          
 21             \ 'z': 45,                                                          
 20             \ 'warning': 12,                                                    
 19             \ 'error': 80,                                                      
 18             \ }
```

Comment: What does the plugin's documentation say about that?

Comment: @romainl I don't see any part about the with of the section, only a part that tells when should a section be truncated at certain window width, but I have tried setting the truncating threshold small enough, it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:CocList diagnostics` to list all diagnostics, if you have installed coc.nvim plugin. Or you can check the `55` line in your file. You also can diasable it by `"let g:airline_section_error = ''`.